# Can a metamagic rod affect a spell that has been metamagiced to be outside its normal spell level range?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

Say I am a high level cleric. I have [Flame Strike](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/flameStrike.html#flame-strike) prepared with Empower metamagic, increasing it's spell slot by 2, resulting in an Empowered Flame Strike sitting in a level 7 spell slot.

I also have a normal metamagic rod of [Intensify](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) which affects spells of level 6 and lower.

Can I use my metamagic rod when I cast my Empowered Flame Strike? On one hand the level of the spell is still <6, but on the other the slot it uses is >6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than Heighten Spell, no metamagic feat changes a spell’s level, only the slot it requires. Thus, *empowered flame strike* is still a 5th-level spell for the purposes of save DC, passing through *globe of invulnerability* (well, both a 5th-level and 7th-level spell are equally-good at that, but if you had an *empowered fireball* it would not bypass *lesser globe of invulnerability*), and being affected by an *intensify metamagic rod*.

Comment: So if I used Heighten Spell to increase it to 7th level, then it WOULDN'T be usable with the rod. ok.

Comment: I am very glad to see this answer as I feared it would be the other way around.